# Unexplainable timings for different optimisations

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm writing some code which has to apply a different algorithm to a large data set, depending upon a setting. The data set is large, and real-world timings have indicated that we need to optimise this if possible.

The selected algorithm has to be run on many subsets of data from a large array. I therefore decided to try several different approaches:

1. Intialise a `Func<>` delegate to reference the required algorithm. Call this delegate from within the main loop.
2. Loop over the data and call the appropriate algorithm from within the main loop.
3. Call a separate method which implements the main loop itself for each algorithm .

In my tests, I had each approach calling the same underlying method, `calculate()`. (Of course, the real code calls a different method for each algorithim, but here I am testing the quickest way of calling the algorithm, not the algorithm itself.)

Each of the tests call the required algorithm in a loop `ITERS` times.

In this test code, `DataReductionAlgorithm` is just an enum that defines the various algorithms. It's not really used other than to simulate what would happen in real code.

Here is my test implementation for approach (1). It's very straightforward: Assign the `Func<> a` to the algorithm to be called, then call it from a loop:

```
private static void test1(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    Func<int[], int, int, int> a;

    switch (algorithm)
    {
        case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:
            a = calculate;
            break;

        case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:
            a = calculate;
            break;

        default:
            a = calculate;
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
        a(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Here's my test implementation for approach (2). It moves the `if` test for the choice of algorithm outside the loop. I was expecting this to be the fastest approach:

```
private static void test2(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    switch (algorithm)
    {
        case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:

            for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                calculate(data, 0, data.Length);

            break;

        case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:

            for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                calculate(data, 0, data.Length);

            break;

        default:

            for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                calculate(data, 0, data.Length);

            break;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for testing approach (3). If moves the `if` test for the choice of algorithm inside the loop. I was expecting this to be slower that approach (2) because the `if` test is going to be performed `ITERS` times, instead of just once:

```
private static void test3(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
    {
        switch (algorithm)
        {
            case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:

                calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
                break;

            case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:

                calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
                break;

            default:

                calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the strange timing results I was getting, I added a new test which is almost identical to `test2()` except that instead of looping within the switch cases, I call a method to do exactly the same loop.

I therefore expected this to take almost the same time as `test2()`:

```
private static void test4(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
{
    switch (algorithm)
    {
        case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:

            iterate(ITERS, data);
            break;

        case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:

            iterate(ITERS, data);
            break;

        default:

            iterate(ITERS, data);
            break;
    }
}

private static void iterate(int n, int[] data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Here is the entire program, in case anyone wants to try it themselves:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public enum DataReductionAlgorithm
    {
        Single,
        Max,
        Mean
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private const int ITERS = 100000;

        private void run()
        {
            int[] data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).ToArray();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                test1(data, DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean);
                Console.WriteLine("test1: " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                test2(data, DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean);
                Console.WriteLine("test2: " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                test3(data, DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean);
                Console.WriteLine("test3: " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                test4(data, DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean);
                Console.WriteLine("test4: " + sw.Elapsed);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private static void test1(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
        {
            Func<int[], int, int, int> a;

            switch (algorithm)
            {
                case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:
                    a = calculate;
                    break;

                case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:
                    a = calculate;
                    break;

                default:
                    a = calculate;
                    break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                a(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        private static void test2(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
        {
            switch (algorithm)
            {
                case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:

                    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                        calculate(data, 0, data.Length);

                    break;

                case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:

                    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                        calculate(data, 0, data.Length);

                    break;

                default:

                    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                        calculate(data, 0, data.Length);

                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void test3(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
            {
                switch (algorithm)
                {
                    case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:

                        calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
                        break;

                    case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:

                        calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
                        break;

                    default:

                        calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void test4(int[] data, DataReductionAlgorithm algorithm)
        {
            switch (algorithm)
            {
                case DataReductionAlgorithm.Max:

                    iterate(ITERS, data);
                    break;

                case DataReductionAlgorithm.Mean:

                    iterate(ITERS, data);
                    break;

                default:

                    iterate(ITERS, data);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void iterate(int n, int[] data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                calculate(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        private static int calculate(int[] data, int i1, int i2)
        {
            // Just a dummy implementation.
            // Using the same algorithm for each approach to avoid differences in timings.

            int result = 0;

            for (int i = i1; i < i2; ++i)
                result += data[i];

            return result;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**The results**

Firstly, note that these results are from a RELEASE BUILD run from outside the debugger. Running a debug build - or running a release build from the debugger - will give misleading results.

I'm testing a build with .Net 4.51 on Windows 8.1 with a quad core Intel processor. (However, I got similar results with .Net 4.5 and .Net 4.)

I got different results depending on whether it was x64/AnyCPU or x86.

To recap: I was expecting test1() and test3() to be the slowest, and test2() to be the fastest, with test4() being almost the same speed as test2().

Here's the x86 results:

```
test1: 00:00:00.5892166
test2: 00:00:00.5848795
test3: 00:00:00.5866006
test4: 00:00:00.5867143
```

That's kindof what I expected, except that test1() was faster that I thought it would be (possibly indicating that calling a delegate is highly optimised).

Here's the x64 results:

```
test1: 00:00:00.8769743
test2: 00:00:00.8750667
test3: 00:00:00.5839475
test4: 00:00:00.5853400
```

Whoah!

What happened to `test1()` and `test2()`? I can't explain that. How can `test2()` be so much slower than `test3()`?

And why isn't `test4()` pretty much the same speed as `test2()`?

And why the huge difference between x86 and x64?

Can anyone shed any light on this? The difference in speed is not insignificant - it might make the difference between something taking 10 seconds and it taking 15 seconds.

---

**ADDENDUM**

I've accepted the answer below.

However, just to illustrate the fragility of JIT optimisations mentioned by @usr below, consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const int ITERS = 10000;

        private void run()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            int[] data = new int[10000];

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                test1(data, 0);
                var elapsed1 = sw.Elapsed;

                sw.Restart();
                test2(data, 0);
                var elapsed2 = sw.Elapsed;

                Console.WriteLine("Ratio = " + elapsed1.TotalMilliseconds / elapsed2.TotalMilliseconds);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void test1(int[] data, int x)
        {
            switch (x)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                        dummy(data);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void test2(int[] data, int x)
        {
            switch (x)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    loop(data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static int dummy(int[] data)
        {
            int max = 0;

            // Also try with "int i = 1" in the loop below.

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
                if (data[i] > max)
                    max = data[i];

            return max;
        }

        private static void loop(int[] data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; ++i)
                dummy(data);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the line of code underneath the comment `// Also try with "int i = 1" in the loop below.`.

With `i = 0`, I get the following results for release x64 build:

```
Ratio = 1.52235829774506
Ratio = 1.50636405328076
Ratio = 1.52291602053827
Ratio = 1.52803278744701
```

Merely changing that to `i = 1`, I get these results:

```
Ratio = 1.16920209593233
Ratio = 0.990370350435142
Ratio = 0.991150637472754
Ratio = 0.999941245001628
```

Interesting! :)

Comment: I've tested it on my PC, I get similar results on both x86 and x64. Do you use a laptop to perform the test ?

Comment: @AlexH No, it's a desktop. Are you definitely running a release build and not under the debugger?

Comment: Because `calculate` is a very long-running function it should completely dominate the running time of the benchmark. All differences due to the testX functions should disappear in the noise.

Comment: @usr But the differences clearly don't, as the results show. In particular, look at test2() compared to test4(). They really should be almost the same time. (And how would that explain the discrepancies between x86 and x64 in any case?)

Comment: @AlexH I've tried this on some other systems too, with the same results.

Comment: @usr Your results are similar to my results: test2() versus test4() = similar times on x86, different times on x84 (look at the times!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I ran the tests on release mode with VS 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on x64, .NET 4.5, Release, no Debugger.

I have looked at the generated x64 for `test2` and `test3`. The hot inner loop consumes 99% of the time. Only this loop matters.

For `test3`, `calculate` is inlined and the loop bounds are equal to the array bounds. This allows the JIT to eliminate the range check. In `test2` the range check could not be eliminated because the loop bounds are dynamic. They are given by `int i1, int i2` which are not statically known to be valid array bounds. Only inlining can provide that information in the current JIT. Inlining replaces these values by `0, data.Length`.

This does not have to be so. The [Hotspot JVM performs dynamic range check elimination](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/RangeCheckElimination). The .NET JIT is not sophisticated to do this.

`test3` with inlining:

[image]

`test2` with calculate not inlined:

[image]

Two branches instead of one. One is the loop test, one the range check.

I have no idea why the JIT inlined differently here. Inlining is driven by heuristics.

Comment: Interesting. I guess the moral of this is "don't put loops in switch statements - call a method that does the looping". By doing that and transforming `test2()` into `test4()`, we get a 50% speed improvement! I guess the `switch` construct may introduce too much complexity for the JITTER to deal with. By putting the loop into a separate, we simplify it enough for the JITTER to optimise it.

Comment: If you ask me, the switch is kind of unrelated. Who knows what small disturbances can suppress inlining. You cannot reliably protect yourself against that. Compiler heuristics are very fragile. I'd try to move the array bounds computation into the function the loop is in. Use constant zero and `data.Length` as the loop bounds to be safe. Or use unsafe code, although I have seen cases in which that has prevented the JIT from generating good code as well.